# save videos on android device with react-native

Tags: android, api, react-native, axios

I need to save videos from a request in an API, I'm going to use AXIOS, I thought about saving to the device, if that's possible, how do I do it? or can I save these videos in RealmDB?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob) component, very easy to use

After downloading you must save `res.path()` from response to your DB.

Comment: But the format of the file on database is base64, the rn-fetch-blob works?